# Referencing a simple table in RMarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc

I have a table in RMarkdown that i want to reference

```
  Right     Left     Center     Default
-------     ------ ----------   -------
     12     12        12            12
    123     123       123          123
      1     1          1             1

Table:  Demonstration of simple table syntax.
```

Can anyone tell me how to reference it. So basically i want to say Please `see table 1.1 for more detail`

Comment: You could use the pandoc-crossref filter, it works with every output format: https://github.com/lierdakil/pandoc-crossref

Comment: Hi @scoa, Thank you for this. It looks like what i need. As I'm not an expert on pandoc. Can you tell me how to install `pandoc-crossref` filter.

Comment: There are (precompiled binaries for all platforms)[https://github.com/lierdakil/pandoc-crossref/releases/tag/v0.2.4.1a]; however, I think it is better to install it through cabal: [install haskell platform](https://www.haskell.org/platform) and then do `cabal update` and `cabal install pandoc-crossref`. Finally, add `pandoc_args: ["-F=pandoc-crossref"]` to your YAML front matter to run the filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution that does not depend on output format is the [`pandoc-crossref` filter](https://github.com/lierdakil/pandoc-crossref). Whenever you output a table, add a reference to its caption (here with pander):

````
```{r}
library(pander)
tb <- table(sample(letters[1:4], 10, replace=TRUE))
pander(tb, caption= "my table {#tbl:mytable}")
```
````

Then you can reference this table with:

```
see [@tbl:mytable] for more details
```

To run the filter, add this to your YAML front matter:

```
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    pandoc_args: ["-F=pandoc-crossref"]
---
```

Pandoc-crossref can be installed with its [binaries](https://github.com/lierdakil/pandoc-crossref/releases/tag/v0.2.4.1a) or through the [haskell platform](https://www.haskell.org/platform). In the latter case:

```
cabal update
cabal install pandoc-crossref
```